# If condition in Emal Callback - Graylog Opensoure

Tags: email, graylog

Anyone that have exp about configuring email callback on `Graylog`, please advise me this case.
In log that we receive have field: protocol-id. Now I can using it in email by using syntax:

```
${message.fields.protocol-id}.
```

But value of this filed is number. I want to change it to string. I give example:

```
if (protocol-id = 17) protocol-id = 'UDP'.
```

I try code as below but I don't get anything:

```
${if ${message.fields.protocol-id}==17}Protocol-Attack: UDP
```

How I can solve this case???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a stream which contains only those messages (e. g. by adding a stream rule "Field `protocol-id` must be equal to 17"), call it "Protocol-Attack: UDP", and then create an alert condition for this specific stream which will fire if there are any messages in this stream.